# So long and thanks for all the fish

Tags: discussion

Due to [this farewell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342950/227017) and associated persistent abusive behaviour from SE, I will no longer participate in any sites until such a time as SE becomes less abusive.

My thanks go to all users of this (and other) sites, all the best.

Comment: So, where does this leave us in terms of moderators?

Comment: @MacacoBranco I was never a moderator and as far as I know the current ones have neither resigned nor been unceremoniously thrown out.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Best off luck.

Comment: @MacacoBranco No worries whatsoever. Thank you.